# Run Azure Notebook By API (external)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to run the notebook from node, everything is working fine except the parameters are not accepted by the notebook instead it is sending the output based on default params. I am not getting where I am doing wrong.

Below is my call:

```
var job_payload = {
            "run_name": runName,
            "existing_cluster_id": 'cluster_id',
            "notebook_task":
            {
                "notebook_path": notebookPath
            },
            "notebook_params": notebook_params //{'x':1,'y':2}
        }
        
        var url = "https://<location>.<azr_databricks>.net/api/2.0/jobs/runs/submit";
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer token'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(job_payload),
        };
```

My notebook:

```
import json
dbutils.widgets.text("x", '3', "firstParam")
dbutils.widgets.text("y", '4', "secondParam")
x=int(dbutils.widgets.get("x"))
y=int(dbutils.widgets.get("y"))
sum=x+y
class Output:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.resultTest2 = val

p1 = Output(sum)
print(p1.resultTest2)
result=json.dumps(p1.__dict__)
#RETURNING THE OUTPUT
dbutils.notebook.exit(result)
```

I am sending x:1 and y:2 as param but instead of getting output 3 I am getting 7 which is default value.

As I am not getting much help from the documentation, please help:

Document URL: [Microsoft link](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer that where I was wrong from the below link :

[StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758094/i-o-operations-with-azure-databricks-rest-jobs-api)

the job_payload will look like below:

```
var job_payload = {
            "run_name": runName,
            "existing_cluster_id": 'cluster_id',
            "notebook_task":
            {
                "notebook_path": notebookPath,
                "base_parameters":notebook_params //{'x':1,'y':2}
            },
           
        }
        
        var url = "https://<location>.<azr_databricks>.net/api/2.0/jobs/runs/submit";
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer token'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(job_payload),
        };
```

Now, it is working fine.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. After 48 hours, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.